# Groovy: Deep comparison of Java beans without equals() as in Unitils assertReflectionEquals?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, equals

Has Groovy a simple solution for comparing two Java beans with nested beans without using their equals(), i.e. comparing all primitive/java.lang.* fields in them and then do the same recursively for the remaining fields? In the case of inequality I'd of course like to get a nice report about what was eqaul and what wasn't. Unitils' [assertReflectionEquals](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html) does exactly that but I was wondering if there is something similar directly in Groovy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Groovy runtime itself has no such thing for general classes, no.